How to handle a DB concurrency conflict when using a SumAsync() call?
I have a site that registers students to classes and uses a "Token" system as payments to register. Ex. 5 tokens to register.
When a payment is made to register for a class, I create 2 rows (Payment, Token) shown below. First I get the total tokens a user has in his account by running a .SumAsync() call.
My concern - If the SumAsync() call is run simultaneously (website, backend Azure Function) returning the same token sum, then both processes proceed to alter TokensBefore and TokensAfter for a new Payment, I'll end up with one TokensAfter being incorrect.
Question - Is there a way to prevent this? The only solution I can think of is to create another table (Ex. TotalTokens) that stores the total sum value of each users tokens and have a concurrency check on that row and value. Or have an additional field in Token that's called TotalTokens and have some sort of lock on the UserId, if that's possible?

// 2 calls below can end with an incorrect TokensAfter in Payment, if both SumAsync's are called before first Payment is saved.

// on website
var tokens = await _dbContext.Tokens
    .Where(p => p.UserId == userId)
    .SumAsync(p => p.Tokens);

var newPayment = new Payment {
  Type = Type.Registration,
  TokensBefore = tokens,
  TokensAfter = tokens-5, // for registration

  Token = new Token() {
    Tokens = -5,
    UserId = userId
  }
}

// in Azure Function
var tokens = await _dbContext.Tokens
    .Where(p => p.UserId == userId)
    .SumAsync(p => p.Tokens);

var newPayment = new Payment {
  Type = Type.TokenPurchase,
  TokensBefore = tokens,
  TokensAfter = tokens+50, // for purchase

  Token = new Token() {
    Tokens = 50,
    UserId = userId
  }
}


Make sure you always update a record, for example a Token, using optimistic concurrency control.

With any data system you should aim to avoid multiple sources of truth. For instance a payment shouldn't record an old & new value but simply a datetime and a delta, I.e. -5 vs. +50. Any historical view of token state can be built using the date/time of the token records and/or payments.

Hi Steve. Thanks for the advice.
